# What is the function of create command in migrations?

Tags: php, laravel

What is the function of (while making migrations such as in
 `php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users`??
What if I didn't use it?

Comment: What do you mean by "function"?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#generating-migrations `The --table and --create options may also be used to indicate the name of the table and whether or not the migration will be creating a new table. These options pre-fill the generated migration stub file with the specified table`

Comment: `make` command is used for creating files and add code template for development. You may skip this and create files manually. `php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users` this command will create a file in `database/migrations` directory with a pre-populated code template. This is only meant for simplifying development.

Comment: sorry error in syntax. the question should be :What is the function of create while making migrations such as in php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users?? What if i didn't use it?

Comment: can i write php artisan make:migration create_users_table  without --create command?

Comment: Yes you could. If you use `--create` flag, then the migration file's `up()` method will have the following template: `Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {}` if it is not used, then an empty `up()` will be there

Answer (score 0):

create command sets the name of the table in the generated file.
If the migration is in the form "create__table", there's no need to specify the table name as laravel automatically picks up the table name inteded. But if you are creating a migration for alteration like " php artisan add_name_column_to_users_table", no blueprint will be generated if you do not specify the --create argument.